# Gradel Build problem in Android Studio 4.1

Tags: android, android-studio

After updating Android Studio to v4.1 I am facing a weird issue.
This problem occurs when I leave my PC to idle for few hours or put it to sleep mode when Android Studio is open in background. 
When I come back and try to Run 'app' it started to give me gradel build error without giving any additional information.

[image: build error]

On digging deeper, I found that this issue is somehow related to OpenJDK Platform Binary. When building the project, android studio keeps creating a new process for "OpenJDK Platform Binary" in every 1-2 seconds. Sometime process counts cross 100+ until memory runs out and OS started to kill it.

[image: process stack]

Even after closing the Android Studio these Open JDK process stay in the memory stack and I have to terminate them manually. This build error persists until I restart my PC. 

Please tell me if there is any permanent solution for this because I cannot restart my PC multiple time.


Android Studio Information:

```
Android Studio 4.1
Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6858069, built on September 23, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1246M
Cores: 4
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true, ide.balloon.shadow.size=0
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.intellij.plugins.markdown, org.jetbrains.kotlin, com.markskelton.one-dark-theme, com.chrisrm.idea.MaterialThemeUI
```